# powerset of difference ⊆ differences of powersets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We wish to prove $P(A-B)\subseteq P(A)-P(B)$ where $P(X)$ represents the power set and $-$ represents set difference.

My attempt:

$ x \in P(A-B) \implies x\subseteq A-B \implies x\subseteq A \text{ and } x\not\subseteq B \implies x\in P(A)\text{ and }x\notin P(B) \implies x\in P(A)-P(B) $

I know it is not true (since $\emptyset$ is in one but not the other), but what in the way is wrong?

thank you

Comment: A few typesetting notes: use `\implies` for $\implies$.  Also, the problem statement should be included in the body and typeset.  Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more information on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ here.

Comment: $\Phi \subseteq A-B$, and $\Phi \subseteq A$ and $\Phi \subseteq B$.

Comment: $x\subseteq A-B$ implies that $x\subseteq A$ and that $x\cap B=\emptyset$.  It does not imply that $x\not\subseteq B$.  That is to say, given that $x\subset A-B$ one has that every element of $x$ (*if any exist in the first place*) must be an element of $A$ and must not be an element of $B$.  In the case that $x$ is nonempty, yes this will imply $x\not\subseteq B$ but it is a much stronger statement than that and fails when $x$ is empty.

Comment: $x \subset A - B$ does not imply $x \not \subset B$.  As you point out $\emptyset \subset A-B$ and $\emptyset \subset B$.

Comment: Oh wow. I answered myself and couldn't notice it, sorry for such unnecessary question. and thank you!

Comment: The statement is not true as $\emptyset \in P(A-B)$ but $\emptyset \not \in P(A) - P(B)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the implication $x \subseteq A \setminus B \implies x \subseteq A$ and $x \not \subseteq B$. In fact the example you mention, the empty set $x = \emptyset$, demonstrates what goes wrong here. Clearly $\emptyset \subseteq A \setminus B$, but also $\emptyset \subseteq B$.