# power set $(A-B)-\{\emptyset\} \cup$ power set $(B-A) \cup- \{\emptyset\} \subset $ power set $A$ $\triangle$ power set $(B)$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Prove $(\mathcal{P}(A-B)-\{\emptyset\}) \cup (\mathcal{P}(B-A)-\{\emptyset\}) \subset  \mathcal{P}(A) \triangle \mathcal{P}(B)$. Note $\mathcal{P}(A) \triangle \mathcal{P}(B) = (\mathcal{P}(A)-\mathcal{P}(B)) \cup (\mathcal{P}(B)-\mathcal{P}(A))$.

**Attempt**. Thanks to this problem of [power set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565566/powerset-of-difference-%E2%8A%86-differences-of-powersets) we know that $\mathcal{P}(A-B)$ is not a subset of $\mathcal{P}(A)- \mathcal{P}(B)$ but is it true $\mathcal{P}(A-B) - \{\emptyset\} \subset \mathcal{P}(A) - \mathcal{P}(B)$? if it's true we finish the problem, could you help me please?

Comment: If $X$ is a non-empty subset of $A\setminus B$, is $X$ a subset of $A$? Is $X$ a subset of $B$? Once you’ve answered those, it should be clear whether $X$ is in $\wp(A)\setminus\wp(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

element chase.

Let $X\in (P(A-B)-\{\emptyset\})\cup (P(B-A)-\{\emptyset\})$ then either $X\in (P(A-B)-\{\emptyset\})$ or $X\in (P(B-A)-\{\emptyset\})$.

so either $X$ is a nonempty subset of $A-B$ or $X$ is a nonempty subset of $B-A$.

If the former then $X$ is a subset of $A$ but contains no elements of $B$. So $X$ is a subset of $A$ but not a subset of $B$.  So $X \in P(A)$ but $X\not \in P(B)$ so $X \in P(A)\Delta P(B)$.

And if the latter then $X$ is a subset of $B$ but contains no elements of $A$. So $X$ is a subset of $B$ but not a subset of $A$.  So $X \in P(B)$ but $X\not \in P(A)$ so $X \in P(A)\Delta P(B)$

Either way $X \in P(A)\Delta P(B)$ and  $(P(A-B)-\{\emptyset\})\cup (P(B-A)-\{\emptyset\})\subset P(A)\Delta P(B)$.